# iOS Module map: Is it possible to setup multiple umbrella headers for frameworks

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

Is it possible to have one "module.map" that works for two frameworks? I have an iOS and OSX framework inside the same project and I need an umbrella header to work for both of them. I can create a separate module.map for each of them, but I would really like to have just one. This is what I have so far.

```
framework module FrameWorkiOS {
    umbrella header "Class.h"
    requires objc
}

 framework module FrameworkMac {
    umbrella header "Class.h"
    requires objc
}
```

Doesn't work however. It says the following

> "Umbrella for module 'FrameWork_iOS' already cover this directory"

regarding the following code `umbrella header "Class.h"`